# scipy imshow conflict with El Capitan SIP and /var/folders/

Tags: python, scipy, osx-elcapitan, imshow

I run into some permission issues and I am sure there is a quick fix, but I can't find it.

Setup: Mac, OSX: El Capitan, Anaconda, Python3.5.1

From bash (make Preview the default viewer):

`export SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER=/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview`

From interpreter:

```
import scipy.misc as mi

im1 = mi.imread('local_filename.png')
mi.imshow(im1)
```

Spits the following error from Preview: The file “tmph_9q7lwu.png” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.

The path of this file is in: /var/folders/w4/wrnzszgd41d7064lx64nc10h0000gn/T/

Its permissions are: -rw------, Preview app's UID: 501 (myself)

I feel that this is an El Capitan SIP (system integrity protection) issue, which leads me to my question:

1. is there a way to make scipy write temporary files to a folder
   accessible by Preview,
2. or, is there a way to give Preview permission to
   read out of /var/folder/ without disabling SIP.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason behind trying to open files from /var/?

Do the files open when they are not in /var/?

Comment: So when imshow() is invoked, it converts the im1 object into a png image, and then stores it in a temporary file. It then passes that temporary file to the prescribed 'viewer', in this case I made it Preview. But, for some reason Preview fails to open it throwing the error cited above. The files open fine when I open them manually from /var/folders/...

Comment: Interesting - I wasn't aware of the temp files when using an external app for viewing. I'll think some more about what could be causing the permissions error.

Comment: @MaxwellGrady Yeah its weird, if you do `/path/to/preview/executable /path/to/temp/file` in bash it spits out permissions error. But if you do `open /path/to/temp/file` it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a little hack that works, there are two steps:

Within pilutil.py, editing lines 381+ (under the def imshow),

```
import os
import time #Me: 1. needed later
os.close(fnum)

cmd = os.environ.get('SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER', 'see') 
cmd = 'open'  #Me: 2. User added line
print(fname)
status = os.system("%s %s" % (cmd, fname))

time.sleep(0.1) #Me: 1.    
os.unlink(fname)
```

Step 1. Preview needs a time delay (0.05 was too fast). Otherwise the unlink deletes the file before Preview displays it correctly.

Step 2. Using `open` instead of the `$SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER` reference to the Preview app works. The latter method has a more general error.

There is a larger problem though, which I might raise in a separate post. From within bash:

```
/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview /path/to/file
```

This should cause Preview to open the file. But instead it raises the permissions error, seemingly regardless of where the file is located.